# How to set a boolean to true in smali

Tags: android, smali

```
.line 71
invoke-static {v1}, Ljava/lang/Boolean;->valueOf(Z)Ljava/lang/Boolean;
move-result-object v0
iput-object v0, p0, Lcom/tadasa/tadasaful/zxs;->isTrial:Ljava/lang/Boolean;
```

I want the `isTrial` to boolean `True`.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use iput-boolean like this

```
const/4 v0, 0x1
iput-boolean v0, p0, Lcom/example/myapplication/Test;->isTrial:Z
```